I got a p2 vls ts visa when I should have gotten a p3 vls visa
The consulate should have issued a p3 vls visa but instead issued a p2 vls ts visa. Can I apply for a card de sejure as soon as I enter France?

A VLS TS (valid as a residence card) is issued when your stay is between 4 months and 12 months
If you want to stay further in France, you must apply for a titre de séjour within 2 months of the expiration of your VLS-TS

If you wish stay in France, you must file a application for a residence card within 2 months before the end of your visa to the prefecture or sub-prefecture of your home.

